# Insert into database problem... (Bad character coding) PHP/MYSQL

Tags: php, mysql, utf-8, insert, character

I have a form which is submitted into a mysql database.
The database is set to UTF-8_GENERAL and the rows are using the same character coding as well.

But when I submit the form with a "ő" or "ű" in the text, it does not submit anything after these characters.
(Example: "This is a nice ű day." It just inserts this into the db: "This is a nice")

The form validation page has the 
    mysql_real_escape_string(); 
    strip_tags();
before submitting to the db.

How could I solve this?
Any help appreciated...

Comment: What does your query look like before it's executed? Could be something in PHP is mangling the characters before it ever hits the database.

Comment: have you checked that the html is using utf8 as well using the [charset meta tag](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Character_encodings_in_HTML)?

Comment: I have checked the html. It is using utf-8 as well.

Answer (score 3):

Its good that you are using mysql_real_escape_string()!

I think the problem might be, that in some side-step form page -> header file -> core file -> mysql macro file -> inserting to DB etc.. If you are using some CMS method of course.

So basically:

1. Make sure that all your tables and cells in mysql are UTF8
2. Add this to your mysql macro or right after you create mysql connection: `mysql_query("SET NAMES utf8");`
3. Add this to your core file or on the top of your php page: `Header("Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8");`
4. And of course the meta-tag, that sets encoding in the html/template file.

If you have mastered those steps, it should be fixed. If not, then at least you have debuged out alot of possible issues :)

Comment: Thanks... I have forgot the most basic steps ;)