# Mysql insert problem! (UTF8 characters don't show)

Tags: php, mysql, utf-8, phpmyadmin, character

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Insert into database problem… (Bad character coding) PHP/MYSQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6862025/insert-into-database-problem-bad-character-coding-php-mysql)

I have a form which is submitted into a mysql database. The database is set to `UTF-8_GENERAL` and the rows are using the same character coding as well.

But when I submit the form with a "ő" or "ű" in the text, it does not submit anything after these characters. (Example: "This is a nice ű day." It just inserts this into the db: "This is a nice")

The form validation page has the `mysql_real_escape_string()`; `strip_tags()`; before submitting to the db.

I echo out the result after every string function (mentioned above). It all works fine, but when it gets inserted, it doesn't display anything after those characters.

```
[MySql version: 5.0.51a-24+lenny5-log | Using phpMyAdmin version: 2.11.8.1deb5+lenny7]
```

How could I solve this? Any help appreciated...

Answer (score 0):

encode the characters:

`$string = mb_convert_encoding($variable, 'HTML-ENTITIES', 'UTF-8');`

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but it doesn't work :(

Comment: What happens? Show your insert statement as well.

Comment: Everything works well in the PHP file. I get every character right (in the insert statement as well), but in the database... There is the problem.

Comment: you are being incredibly vague, what happens in the db? paste your insert code.

Comment: $sql="INSERT INTO test (text, time)
VALUES
('$text','$time')";

if (!mysql_query($sql,$con))
  {
  die('Error: ' . mysql_error());
  }    ($test contains the "ő")

Comment: did you `$text = mb_convert_encoding($text, 'HTML-ENTITIES', 'UTF-8');` before the insert?

Comment: Yes, but it doesn't work either. Maybe there is a problem with db.